# What is the best way to combine (merge) 2 JSONObjects?

Tags: java, android, json

What is the best way to combine (merge) two `JSONObjects`?

```
JSONObject o1 = {
    "one": "1",
    "two": "2",
    "three": "3"
}
JSONObject o2 = {
        "four": "4",
        "five": "5",
        "six": "6"
    }
```

And result of combining `o1` and `o2` must be

```
JSONObject result = {
        "one": "1",
        "two": "2",
        "three": "3",
        "four": "4",
        "five": "5",
        "six": "6"
    }
```

Comment: Which language do you refer to?

Comment: What do you want it to do if both objects contain the same key?

Comment: go through the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403132/concat-multiple-jsonobjects

Comment: @TomHart, no. No same keys in both objects.

Comment: Use the JSONObject `keys()` to get an iterator of the keys in the objects, and `while(iterator.hasNext())` through both objects, and all the values to a new object `newObj.add(key, oldObj.get(key);`

Comment: @TomHart, thanks. This is one of solutions. May be someone know the better one.

Comment: See full implementation of merge two JSON Tree in Deep here :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/41135481/2685581

Answer (score 14):

I have your same problem: I can't find the `putAll` method (and it isn't listed in the [official reference page](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)).

So, I don't know if this is the best solution, but surely it works quite well:

```
//I assume that your two JSONObjects are o1 and o2
JSONObject mergedObj = new JSONObject();

Iterator i1 = o1.keys();
Iterator i2 = o2.keys();
String tmp_key;
while(i1.hasNext()) {
    tmp_key = (String) i1.next();
    mergedObj.put(tmp_key, o1.get(tmp_key));
}
while(i2.hasNext()) {
    tmp_key = (String) i2.next();
    mergedObj.put(tmp_key, o2.get(tmp_key));
}
```

Now, the merged JSONObject is stored in `mergedObj`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I this is the same like @TomHart proposed in comments.

Comment: This merge is a shallow one, i.e. nested objects are overridden rather than merged

Answer (score 3):

json objects to be merge in that new json object like this.

```
    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    jObj.put("one", "1");
    jObj.put("two", "2");
    JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject();
    jObj2.put("three", "3");
    jObj2.put("four", "4");


    JSONParser p = new JSONParser();
    net.minidev.json.JSONObject o1 = (net.minidev.json.JSONObject) p
                        .parse(jObj.toString());
    net.minidev.json.JSONObject o2 = (net.minidev.json.JSONObject) p
                        .parse(jObj2.toString());

    o1.merge(o2);

    Log.print(o1.toJSONString());
```

now o1 will be the merged json object.
you will get the output like this ::

```
{"three":"3","two":"2","four":"4","one":"1"}
```

please refer this link and download the smartjson library ..here is the link http://code.google.com/p/json-smart/wiki/MergeSample

hope it will help.

Comment: I don't believe doing it that way would give the output required in the OP

Comment: @Neurenor -  that way will give the wrong output. see question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not want to include in my project  third-party libraries for such small operations.

Comment: i have googled it and find this thing.it is easier to use.may be you will implement the code for this but they already have implemented and there is nothing bad in using library if it saves your time.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
            Iterator iterator = json2.keys();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                String key = iterator.next().toString();
                json1.put(key,map.optJSONObject(key));
            }
```

Comment: What is the type of variable map

Answer (score 0):

Merge JsonObject(gson)-

```
JsonObject data = new JsonObject();
data = receivedJsoData.get("details").getAsJsonObject();

JsonObject data2 = new JsonObject();
data2 = receivedJsoData1.get("details").getAsJsonObject();

JsonObject mergedData = new JsonObject();

Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries = data1.entrySet();  //will return members of your object
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries) {
    mergedData.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entries1 = data2.entrySet();  //will return members of your object
for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : entries1) {
    mergedData.add(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.. hope it helps

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.putAll(o1);
result.putAll(O2);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find "putAll" method in org.json.JSONObject [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: putAll will replace all the current mappings which is in the result jsonobject, meaning, when o1 object is put and then the o2 object is also put, o1 would be replaced and only o2 will remain in result object