# Compare elements in two ArrayList and merge

Tags: java, android, arraylist

Second question of the day :)

I have two ArrayLists containing data from two different Json APIs like:

**coinList**

```
coinList = new ArrayList<>();
priceLIst = new ArrayList<>();

    coinList: [{coin=Litecoin, confirmed=0.00}, {coin=Bitcoin, confirmed=0.00}, {coin=Zcoin, confirmed=0.00}]
```

**priceList**

```
priceList: [{coin=Bitcoin, price=1000}, {coin=Litecoin, price=1000}, {coin=Zcoin, price=1000}]
```

Is there a way to add the "price" for the second list to the first one where indexes **coin** match? Like, Bitcoin price to the Bitcoin in the first list and so on? The coins are in different orders in each list, but are formated the same. The idea would be to end up with a list like:

```
mergedList = new ArrayList<>();

    mergedList: [{coin=Litecoin, confirmed=0.00, price=1000}, {coin=Bitcoin, confirmed=0.00, price=1000}]
```

Obviously, the data in the lists is for ilustration purposes only :P The real lists contain a few more things for each coin in the first list, but, unless I'm much mistaken, that should not matter.

Hopefully this makes sense. I'm very new to this stuff, so any help would be appreciated, especially very *noob* friendly help! :)

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32850923/9025311

Comment: for (Price price : priceList) {
   for (Coin coin : coinList) {
    if(price.getId().equals(coin.getCoin())) {
     coinPriceList.add(new CoinPrice(price.getId(), coin.getConfirmed(), price.getPrice()));
    }
   }
  }

Comment: @D.'s might be me, but that does not seem to work with ArrayList<>, or at least I can't get it to work. :( I did change the _priceList_ so that now, instead of **id** the key is **coin**, same as the _coinList_, but still not sure how to proceed.