# Concat two json objects in java

Tags: java, json

I want to concat multiple json object.

I have two json like this

```
{"message":"test","status":"0"}
```

and this

```
{"message":"test-2","status":"1"}
```

result must be

```
[{"message":"test","status":"0"},{"message":"test-2","status":"1"}]
```

How can I do this in Java ?

Comment: You want to concat the values from JSON objects, or you want to create array of them ? You can refer to another link on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403132/concat-multiple-jsonobjects

Comment: I can't use concat with json object.I want to create array of them

Comment: Do you want to handle them as `String`s or as `JSONObject`s in a `JSONArray`?

Comment: I want to handle  them as String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("{\"message\":\"test\",\"status\":\"0\"}");
array.add("{\"message\":\"test-2\",\"status\":\"1\"}");
array.toString();
```

If you want to user support for JSON object in Java, consider using Gson:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JsonObject json1 = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse("{\"message\":\"test\",\"status\":\"0\"}");
        JsonObject json2 = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse("{\"message\":\"test-2\",\"status\":\"1\"}");
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        array.add(json1);
        array.add(json2);
        System.out.println(array.toString());
    }
}
```

This would give you what you want this time using objects.

Comment: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7 for line 1

Comment: And generics is not allowed before 1.5! So what?!

Comment: Just do: new ArrayList<String>()

Comment: It's fixed but I have one more problem,I have to use this add method with jsonobject.But add method is only accepting string value.What can I do ?

Comment: @TolgayToklar What JSONObject are you using?

Comment: I am using socket.io for java and socket event returning jsonobject for json data.

Comment: I am getting this error The method parse(String) in the type JsonParser is not applicable for the arguments (JSONObject) for jsonparser method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58871/discussion-between-shlomi33-and-tolgay-toklar).

Answer (score 5):

You can easily use `JSONObject.toString()` and concatenate the strings easily
e.g

```
String x = "[" + obj1.toString() "," + obj2.toString() + "]";
```

or

```
StringBuilder newStr = new StringBuilder() ;
newStr.append("[").append(obj1.toString()).append(",").append(obj2.toString());
```

Comment: missed a + between obj1.toString()  and ","

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void concatJSON() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(new File(Main.class.getResource("/file/user.json").toURI())));

JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) obj; //usernameJsonObj

String [] values = {"0.9" , Date.from(Calendar.getInstance().toInstant()).toLocaleString()},
        innermost = {"Accomplished", "LatestDate"}, 
        inner = {"Lesson1", "Lesson2", "Lesson3", "Lesson4"};
String in = "Jayvee Villa";

JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < innermost.length; i++)
    jo1.put(innermost[i], values[i]);

JSONObject jo2 = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < inner.length; i++)
    jo2.put(inner[i], jo1);

JSONObject jo3 = new JSONObject();
jo3.put(in, jo2);

String merger = jsonObj.toString().substring(0, jsonObj.toString().length()-1) + "," +jo3.toString().substring(1);

System.out.println(merger);
FileWriter pr = new FileWriter(file);
pr.write(merger);
pr.flush();
pr.close();
}
```