# How I can add item from json and manually?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

I'm fetching 6 items from json. But I also want to add manually some items.

For example like this:
https://image.ibb.co/cUvEuJ/main_qimg_432fcb81bdce8f7e9c42d4cf4a7b2acf.jpg

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you check `JSONObject` / `JSONArray`  documentation? they have methods to add / modify data

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `put()` method in JSONArray

```
// parser class to parser the string
JSONArray array = Parser.parse(jsonString);
// adding manually some items
array.put("some string");
//adding some boolean
array.put(false);
//add some integer
array.put(10);
//add some JSONObject
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject()
obj.put("key","value");
array.put(obj)
```

so you can create jsonObject or java basic variable types and add them manually to jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution for javascript:

`var jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}];`

`var jsonArray2 = [{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];`

`jsonArray1 = jsonArray1.concat(jsonArray2);`

`// jsonArray1 = [{'name': "doug", 'id':5}, {'name': "dofug", 'id':23}, 
//{'name': "goud", 'id':1}, {'name': "doaaug", 'id':52}];`

For java:

[Concat two json objects in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180667/concat-two-json-objects-in-java)